# Why the host of the gitlab url appears encoded

Tags: gitlab

why does my local gitlab generate project clone urls the following way:

```
http://84fdf6ccc7dc/test/testproject.git
```

And how can i either

1. clone the repo using this url and authenticate it with username and password or
2. change the url host to use the host PC IP address which I use to access it using my browser;
   http://10.240.1.2/test/testproject.git

I have used the following command to create the docker image.

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --publish 8803:443 --publish 8800:80 --publish 8822:22 \
  --name gitlab1 \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME_TEST1/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME_TEST1/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME_TEST1/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [the documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab) is often a good starting point...

> To change the external URL:
>
> 1. Optional. Before you change the external URL, determine if you have previously defined a custom Home page URL or After sign-out path. Both of these settings might cause unintentional redirecting after configuring a new external URL. If you have defined any URLs, remove them completely.
>
>    Edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and change `external_url` to your preferred URL:
>
> `external_url "http://gitlab.example.com"`
>
> Alternatively, you can use the IP address of your server:
>
> `external_url "http://10.0.0.1"`
>
> In the previous examples we use plain HTTP. If you want to use HTTPS, see how to configure SSL.
> Reconfigure GitLab:
> `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: Given the current hostname, I'm assuming GitLab is running as a container so the [GitLab Docker images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose) would be relevant, especially the use of `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` for configuration.

Comment: @Ginnungagap I am running a gitlab container. I am new to docker. I have not composed the gitlab docker rather I have downloaded the container and run it.

Comment: @vidarlo In the host PC I have not set external_url, nor in the gitlab image.

Comment: @sunnyboy You should set it. If you use docker, follow the link from Ginnungagap.

Comment: @vidarlo 1st thing is that I can access my gitlab from outside the host PC using the url http://10.240.1.2. 2nd is that if I put the hostname during image creation, I think we need a DNS and that is difficult in our organization. So my best bet is using the current way of accessing our gitlab using IP. Therefore I'm doubtful if GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG will solve my problem.

Comment: It will. Read the documentation. It ***explicitly*** mentions that you can use the IP. In addition, it should take you about thirty seconds to test it, by spinning up a new instance, without *any* risk to your current environment.

Comment: The variable doesn't control how you access it; it controls how gitlab references itself. It's meant for your scenario - where hostname doesn't match the desired name (or IP).  I have *never* touched gitlab, even as a end user, but it was rather trivial to find the documentation. If you want to host gitlab, it's probably smart to be somewhat familiar with the manual.

Comment: @vidarlo Thank you. I was able to solve it using the GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG variable. But I did not have to set the external_url. If you or Ginnungagap could answer it mentioning the use of the variable, I could select it as the answer.

Comment: It's the same option, just different placing dependent on what setup you're using...